# Getting ORA Oracle error code using PHP function oci_connect?

Tags: php, oracle

The PHP function oci_connect (which connects to an Oracle database) just returns false if it fails, which at the moment I handle like this:

```
$connection = oci_connect($username, $password, $database);
if (!$connection){
    return $result = "Trouble connecting to the Oracle Database";
}
```

But really I'd like to have the actual ORA error code, so I can be more informative. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried examining the results of [oci_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php)?

I haven't used Oracle with PHP (sadly) but the MySQL the general pattern is:

```
if (!mysql_connect(...)) {
  error_log('Error connecting: ' . mysql_error()); // or just die
}
```

It seems logical that the Oracle pattern would be:

```
if (!oci_connect(...)) {
  error_log('Error connecting: ' . oci_error());
}
```